# Mold or Floating Yeast?

Tags: yeast, mead, mold

There is floating debris in my mead—Is this a cause for concern?

Some context: I fermented honey water with Red Star Premier Blanc wine yeast, nearly 4 weeks ago. Two weeks ago, I transferred the mead into another carboy for secondary fermentation, added in toasted oak chips, and a Campden tablet. 1 week ago, I removed the oak chips, and transferred the mead into a new carboy. The mead still has not cleared up, and I just noticed some floating debris with bubbles. Is this just yeast that got kicked up, and is this normal? Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Looks totally fine to me. Likely some yeast rafts kicked up when the mead got aerated when racking into another container.

Answer (score 2):

OP's pic sure looks like normal yeast activity.

Any bubbly, fuzzy looking stuff or rafts with "tendrils" stretching outward (like in the pic below) can be a cause for concern. OP just has some yeast bobbing around and a few rafts of bubbles floating on top.

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting your photo shows a good or bad ferment?   It looks like a Brettanomyces pellicle - Ref: https://www.brewer-world.com/pellicles-and-microbes-in-beer/

Comment: @Kingsley - I went back and read my answer. Yeah, it's a little hard to tell what I'm saying. I've edited it for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it's probably yeast rafts, from what I can see. According to City Steading Brewing (which puts out a lot of YouTube videos on homebrewing wines, ciders, and meads), if you think it might be yeast rafts but you aren't sure, swirl the must inside the jug to mix in the floaties (try not to splash). Check back in a couple of days. If the floaties don't come back, it was almost certainly yeast rafts. If the floaties do come back it may be an infection.
Also, if there are any floaties that are vibrantly colored (green, blue, etc.), definitely dump the must and sanitize all your equipment thoroughly before making a new batch.